# Oracle SQL*Plus Variable Declaration

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, sqlplus

I can't for the life of me find out to get the behavior I want:

> old:insert into build_pc
>   values (&&buildA, 35,40,32,29,26,22,22,null,13,11,7,1,999)
>   new:insert into build_pc
>   values (build_id_seq.nextval, 35,40,32,29,26,22,22,null,13,11,7,1,999)
>   1 rows inserted.

As part of an SQL transaction I'm trying to save a variable, moreover an integer ID number, so that it can be entered in a few places across the transaction. The problem is SQLDev is being too clever and converting back to he nextval function each time instead of just storing an int.

Google says use set, but that throws this:

> SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set buildA = build_id_seq.nextval

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you want to use a bind variable in SQL Plus. Please, try this:

```
variable buildA NUMBER;
exec select build_id_seq.nextval into :buildA from dual;
insert into build_pc values (:buildA, 35,40,32,29,26,22,22,null,13,11,7,1,999);
```

If you use 11g you do not need to SELECT the value of sequence, you can use:

```
variable buildA NUMBER;
exec :buildA := build_id_seq.nextval;
insert into build_pc values (:buildA, 35,40,32,29,26,22,22,null,13,11,7,1,999);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had no idea what we are using, but it appears to be 12c:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production. 
Your solution is exactly what I was looking for, but I'm getting some strange behaviour. When I create a second variable, buildB, in the same fashion, it throws undeclared, but after a few attempts starts working fine. Ive no idea whats changing.

Comment: Hi. I am glad it helped. If it still works this strange way, maybe you can post your code with buildB, so I can have a look at the reasons of this behaviour.

Comment: After further discussion with my lecturer (CS Undergrad) my approach was quite the way off. I'd misunderstood transactions, and as such its not surpising the code failed or behaved erratically. For what I asked though, your answer was great. Will mark answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using define rather than set for a substitution variable:

```
define buildA = build_id_seq.nextval
```

... but it will be substituted verbatim wherever you reference `&buildA`, incrementing the sequence each time.

You could use a bind variable or the [new_value](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve013.htm#sthref1333) syntax, but you probably just want to refer to `build_id_seq.nextval` the first time you use it, and `build_id_seq.currval` on all the subsequent references, rather than trying to store it yourself.

As [the documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns002.htm):

> - CURRVAL: Returns the current value of a sequence
> - NEXTVAL: Increments the sequence and returns the next value

So when you call nextval the sequence is incremented, and subsequent calls to currval in the same session get the same value, without incrementing again.

This is useful for creating parent/child records, for example, where you use nextval to create the primary key value and then currval to use the same value as a foreign key in child records.